# How to define a new Routed Event using EventManager class and how to raise this event?

Tags: wpf, routedevents

I came across EventManager class in WPF and found that it can define a new routed event. But I could not understand it correctly through my sources. 
Can someone please explain how EvenManager class define a new Routed event & how to raise this event, with simple example?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with the example in [RegisterRoutedEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventmanager.registerroutedevent.aspx)?

Comment: Thanks Clemens, I got the concept now.